# PS3 Controller is not staying connected

Tags: technical-issues, ps3, controllers

My dad has a PS3, he has not played any games on it with the actual controllers.

When the controller is connected to the usb charger it works perfectly, but when I unplug the remote from the sub which is still in the PS3 the controller's red lights blink then turn off.

I have charged it for 2 almost 3 hours it should work. Why doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The controller is simply broken, it should be independently working fine after you've charged for about 1 hour, sorry to tell you but there's not much you can do other than pay for getting it fixed or pay for another one.